# OpenStack Interactivity between Neutron and Horizon

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

I am curious about the how the horizon interacts with neutron in OpenStack.

For example, when I upload a yaml-file in [Orchestration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqWrL.png), it will show the network topology in [Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coeQi.png).

I am customizing a map which could show the details in each node. So I have to know the interactivity about the neutron and horizon. I do not know how the horizon-level gets the information from neutron-level (specifically says, how can I build the topology from the data in neutron).

Could you please tell why and how the interactivity between launching the stack and building the network topology? Thanks in heart.

Answer (score 0):

Horizon is a Django app which uses Python clients to interact with various OpenStack components (keystone, nova, neutron, etc).

Heat is OpenStack's orchestration engine which creates OpenStack resources from a template.

You have to go through the Horizon code to understand how Horizon-Neutron interaction works.

[Horizon network topology-github](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/tree/master/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/network_topology)